# ASP.NET MVC 3, how should I assign <form> attributes with HtmlHelper.BeginForm?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to assign HTML attributes to forms created with `Html.BeginForm` in ASP.NET MVC 3 views, but it seems I have to use the overload

```
BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
          string actionName, 
          string controllerName, 
          FormMethod method, 
          Object htmlAttributes
)
```

invoking it like this:

```
Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new {id = "my-form"})
```

Is there some easier way to do this, so I can pass e.g. `new {id = "my-form"}` as the only argument to `Html.BeginForm`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there some easier way to do this, so I can pass e.g. new {id = "my-form"} as the only argument to Html.BeginForm?

No, there isn't unless you write your own HTML helper:

```
public static class FormExtensions
{
    public static MvcForm MyBeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return htmlHelper.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@using (Html.MyBeginForm(new { id = "my-form" }))
{
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately you cannot use `BeginForm` as name because there is already an [overload with the same signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470793.aspx) in which the parameter represents `routeValues` though.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own extension method.

```
public static class MyFormExtensions { 
  public static MvcForm BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Object htmlAttributes)
  {
     return htmlHelper.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes);
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you intend to invoke this custom helper on the view?